# Infinite primes history

Tags: prime-numbers, math-history, prime-factorization, prime-gaps, twin-primes

I am little confused with who was the first to modify Euclid's argument of infinitude of primes from $p_{1}p_{2}...p_{r}+1$ to $p_{1}p_{2}...p_{r}-1$? Some writers say it was E.E. Kummer ,($1878$) (Ref: Ribenoim's book 'the new book of prime records') .Some say it was J. Perrot (Ref: Euclid's theorem on the infinitude of primes , Romeo mestrovic, page:$9$, $2$nd last line).
Which one is correct? Any help with the reference will be appreciated. I am adding a picture of Ribenoim's book.

Also I am unable to find the following paper (translation into English , Collected Papers, II, 669–670, Springer, Berlin-Heidelberg, 1975)
E. E. Kummer, Neuer elementarer Beweis des Satzes, dass die Anzahl aller Primzahlen eine unendliche ist, Monatsber. Preuss. Akad. Wiss., Berlin 1878/9, 777–778. [Collected Papers, II, 669–670, Springer, Berlin-Heidelberg, 1975.]

Thanks in advance.[image]

*Added*
[image]
[image]

Comment: The shortest variation is to consider $n!+1$. For references see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem).

Comment: I didn't ask for another variation..I am aware of it and many either proofs available. I am just asking for correct reference.

Comment: Therefore I answered your question. The above comment is another interesting variation - only $4$ symbols in a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kummer wouldn't have bothered to republish Euclid's proof with a $-$ instead of $+$, in particular since the proof does not work if you start with $p_1 = 2$. Kummer's proof uses Euler's phi function; see 
https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/111278#page/880/mode/1up
As a rule, Ribenboim's attributions are to be taken with a large grain of salt. Most of his references in FLT for amateurs aren't worth anything since he didn't check the originals.

P.S. If you're looking for old manuscripts on the web, search for the journal, not the title.

Comment: But the proof mentioned in the book is perfectly fine. Euler also did it by taking at least $3$ primes and proves existence of the other. So why are you starting with exactly one prime and telling the proof doesn't work?

Comment: Yes..I am aware of the above proof done by Kummer using Euler's Phi function . I was curious whether Kummer really mentioned such things in his other papers. Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 2):

According to [Euclid's theorem on the infinitude of primes: a historical survey](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjQ4dv21uXpAhWCCewKHT5WBTsQFjALegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F1202.3670&usg=AOvVaw2h76Wskc-PPWRBV0pxeeYh) it was Perott, who first remarked that $p_1\cdots p_r-1$ also works, see page $9$. The linked paper gives a wealth of historical references.

Comment: I also mentioned the same in my question..is not it? My question is then is ribenoim's claim it was done by Kummer, false?

Comment: The author points out Perott. He should know. He also mentions Kummer right before, but only says "for another elegant variant of Euclid's proof". What have you found in Kummer's work there?

Comment: See the edit.it is the same proof.

Comment: This is only Ribenboim's text. Did you check the original text by Kummer?

Comment: I am not getting that paper in internet...] E. E. Kummer, Neuer elementarer Beweis des Satzes, dass die Anzahl aller Primzahlen eine unendliche ist, Monatsber. Preuss. Akad. Wiss., Berlin 1878/9, 777–778. [Collected Papers, II, 669–670, Springer, Berlin-Heidelberg, 1975.]

Comment: And the same author also referred to this proof the picture of which I added later. That is why I am little confused who was the first to really do it.